# Split Ms Sql 2005 Table to two or more parts

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I need to split an existing table in to two or more tables on Sql Server 2005. The table already has more than a thousand of rows.

For eg current table has cols A, B, C, D, E plus an id column. An I need to add A, B, C rows to another table in another database and add D, E to another table in another database.

I know that it is weird. But I really have to do this.

What is the best approach?

Comment: *Why* do you have to do this?

Comment: A bad db design belongs to the old programmer... Project manager demands a better one. Thus I have to migrate existing data to new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thousand rows is hardly anything. I'm sure even SQL Server can handle millions.

But if you wish to go ahead, you could use the following psuedo code.

```
INSERT INTO SecondTable
SELECT id, A, B, C
FROM CurrentTable

INSERT INTO ThirdTable
SELECT id, D, E
FROM CurrentTable
```

This code assumes your 2nd and 3rd tables are empty. If they're not and you need to match on id's (say) it shouldn't be hard to extend the above code to handle this case.

Comment: A SQL server is only limited by its disk space, memory and available CPU.  Row counts are relative.  In your defense, it can easily handle massive loads if configured properly on a nice machine.

Comment: When denoted that the table has a thousand rows, I just wanted to point that it is not empty. Anyway, it seems that the easiest one is inserting selected values.